# Dart (Flutter) iterate assets folder file content

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a dropdown button in flutter. Its content depends on how many files there is in a folder. For example, I have the following assets folder assets/logos/. This folder has 4 files. Another folder could be assets/monsters/. This folder has 3 files. The first folder would result in a dropdown with the values 1,2,3, and 4. 
I have made the following method:

```
Directory monsterDirectory = new Directory(await rootBundle.loadString(path));
   List skins = monsterDirectory.listSync();
   skins.forEach((skin) {
     skinNumber++;
     amountOfSkins.add(skinNumber.toString());
     skinNumber++;
});
```

Where `path` is the assets path `'assets/collectibles/monsters/astro/'`.
This gives the following error:

```
Directory listing failed, path = 'assets/collectibles/monsters/astro/' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: its because `assets/collectibles/monsters/astro/` folder is a "pseudo" folder - it does not exist in a physical file system